# Setting an absolute position when parent div changes width

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with absolute and relative positioning in css. I have a GUI where folders can be viewed and the user can choose how many columns the folders are viewed in, see pictures. Under each folder i have a input field where the user can change the foldername and also a button to clear the name.

I would like that clear button to always be at an exact position in the text field, but as the width of the columns change, my absolute positioning on the button wont follow as i want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnhi.png - Six columns, the clear button is correctly positioned.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDYvK.png - Three columns, button is not positioned correctly.

```
<div ng-class="colStyle" ng-repeat="folder in getFolders(currentFolder)">                               
    <input type="image" ng-src="{{folder.img}}" ng-click="enter(folder)"/>                              
    <div ng-show="showFont && editing" class="testing">
        <input type="text" ng-model="folder.name"/>                                     
        <img class="clearName" src="img/clear.png" ng-click='clearName($index, folder)'/>                               
    </div>                              
</div>
```

This is my HTML to view my folders and their textfield. class "colStyle" is a responsivegridsystem.com, where the class becomes "col span_1_of_X", where X is the number of columns choosen by the user. This defines how many columns there are in the view ny setting a width of that div.

The two css-classes i think matter here is "testing" and "clearName" which looks like:

```
.testing{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.clearName{
    position: absolute;
    left : 80%;
    top: 5px;
}
```

My problem is that the 80%, or whatever % i choose is good at only one of the number of colums.

How do I set a position on the clear button so that it is always on the same position inside the textfield when the number of columns change?

Comment: You gave left using %. Can you give us a JS fiddle so that we can play around and give you a solution.

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dutue/

Comment: It's a complex system with alot of methods and other things. But I'll try to narrow it down to a fiddle you can try.

Comment: @anurupr setting the width of ".testing input" to 100% is working. I could live with that the whole textfield is wider than the folder just  to make the clear button appear at the same position inside the textfield.

Comment: if you don't want that you could put both the `input` and the `img` in a separate div with style `position:relative` and set a particular width for that

Comment: does the width of the "folder" change? or is it static

Comment: The width of the folder never changes. The only thing that changes is the outer divs width. Should that div be inside the  "colStyle" div? @anurupr

Comment: no it doesn't have to . can you show a screenshot how it looks like when you add the `width:100%` to the input

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8Yx7752.png and http://i.imgur.com/JWiS5dU.png I want the inputfield to always be the same width if possible. But I could live with this as shown in these two images @anurupr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't you start from the right of the input field?

Let us suppose you want to place the clear button 5px from the right side, you can use the following style:

```
.clearName{
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 5px;
}
```

This requires the input box uses the full width of the outer div.

The use of percentage is to dynamically because it depends of the width from the outer div (100px => 80% => 20px and 200px => 80% => 40px).

If you doesn't want to set the input field to the width of the outer div (.testing), you can flip the idea and set the outer div (.testing) to the width of the input field.

For that you can use:

```
.testing {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this has the exakt same result as my current left: 80%. see http://i.imgur.com/PZQk2td.png and http://i.imgur.com/1FVgstk.png

Comment: This is because the input box has a smaller width than the outer div. Use this style to your input field:  .testing input { width: 100%; }   _This requires the input box uses the full width of the outer div._

Comment: Oh, now i understand. Yes that works! But if i don't want to scale the inputbox to the full width of the outer div? I want the inputfield to be as wide as the folder above it? Is that possible?

Comment: Is it ok to scale your outer div depending to the input box? I build a codepen to show you an example: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lBJsg](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lBJsg)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but I can't change the width of "colStyle" Div.

Comment: You shall not change the witdh of the "colStyle" div. Add `display: table;` to your `.testing` div to depend the width on the inner content. In this case your input field.

Comment: This works, i had to change the margins of .testing to auto so that it floats to the center and not get stuck to the left. Thanks!